# querying Account name and substring of the Accounts name values in the same salesforce query

Tags: soql

we have to clean the Accounts where Account Names that has DUP as First word of the Account name ex: DUP ONTARIO INC.
this Deletion can be done only after we make sure they have the original Account with the subset of the same Accounts names
ex: ONTARIO INC.
how to write a query with DUP and Without DUP of the same Account Name

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in a single query because:

- we can't compare two fields to one another in a query
- using multiple filters with a collection of values (i.e. you're using the `IN` keyword) ends up giving you the cartesian product of the filters

You'll need to do processing in Apex (code), Excel, or some similar tool.

You'll also need to make an attempt at it first and make your question as narrow and specific as possible before asking for further help.